# What elements can be inside the time element for HTML5

Tags: html

What elements are allowed in the time element?

Comment: Please check the specification. http://www.w3.org/TR/html5-author/

Answer (score 3):

The `time` element can contain any 'phrasing content' elements, excluding `time`.

Put simply, 'Phrasing content' elements are any elements that are not block-level by default (including 'heading content' (h1, h2, ...) and 'sectioning content' (article, section, ...)).

Some of the 'metadata' elements that have no immediate visible rendering (including script elements) are also 'phrasing content' elements, and all 'embedded' elements (external media, such as object, math and video) are 'phrasing content'. [The HTML5 specification](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/content-models.html#kinds-of-content) has more detail about the types of elements.

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked at the [HTML5 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/text-level-semantics.html#the-time-element) ?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is [here](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/text-level-semantics.html#the-time-element): “[phrasing content](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/content-models.html#phrasing-content)”, but no `time` elements descendants.

Comment: so I can have a script tag inside the time element?

Comment: Yes. `script` is a 'phrasing content' element.

Comment: @Delan: 1) are you sure about the script tag being a phrasing content? 2) nothing says that a phrasing content can include another phrasing content

Comment: Maxim, (1) yes, the `script` is phrasing content. In section 3.2.5.1.5, the list of phrasing content elements includes `script`. (2) even so, it is not relevant in this case. `time` is explicitly stated to be able to contain phrasing content, and `script` is phrasing content.

Comment: @Delan: you are right, that's what is specified in the latest Editor Draft (I based my assumptions by referring to the Working Draft)